# What features of java chronicle map uses to write the data on memory mapped files

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, chronicle

Java chronicle maps/queues write data off the heaps. I am trying to understand what features of java are being used in order to achieve this. I was in assumption that chronicle deals with unsafe API only but unsafe is mostly used in CAS operations. What other feature of java chronicle uses in order to write data into memory-mapped files.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Chronicle Queue uses `Unsafe` for CAS, volatile and order operations, accessing data as `long` or `int` rather than just as `byte`s and 64-bit address access so we can map large regions of memory. We also use a `native` call to map 64-bit regions.